# ISS 7 64 bits WS dll

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I have a Server application DCOM/datasnap ( delphi 7 ), a client application ( calling server by httpsrvr.dll) , and a Web Service DLL ( delphi 7 ) . This dll is call on a asp.net web application . All works fine on a IIS6 web serveur
But problems appeared when i want to install on IIS 7 environnement 64 ( Windows Server 2008 RC2 or Seven 64 bits) :
1 . the http calling doesnt work ( httpsrvr.dll define on ISS7 site web )
2 . the WS call on asp.net (2.0) doesnt work

I have test a Apache 2.2 solution ,   the link client ( exe delphi) server works ( httpsrvr.dll on cgi bin apache directory ) with limitation of oleVariant size ( time out ) 
but i can t setup my dll web service . The URL is like 'http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/WABridge.dll/soap/IWABridge  ( this url is the URL proxy on asp.net application ).
This url doesnt work on IE ( or FF) -> internal error . if i set   'http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/WABridge.dll/IWABridge on FF , i see wsdl definition page but error 404 file not found on asp.net web page ...
TIA , 
Regards

Comment: set pool in the IIS on .Net FrameWork: No Managed, Code Enable 32-bit application: true and Managed Pipeline Mode: Classic

Answer (score 2):

How to run Asapi dll on IIS7.5 (64bit)

Create application pool

1. Open IIS, Add Application Pool
2. Named ‘AppPool32’
3. Change properties:

   - Net Framework Version: No Managed Code
   - Managed Pipeline Mode: Classic
   - Enable 32-bit application: True

Allow Isapi and Cgi

1. On the root of the computername, double click Isapi & Cgi
   Restriction
2. Click Add
3. Browser to your Isapi DLL
4. Check allow extension path to execute

Create the application

1. Right click on the Web Sites > Default Web Site node and click Add
   Application...
2. Choose the alias, application pool, and physical path.  The
   application pool you choose should be the ‘AppPool32’ one you just
   created.

Allow ISAPI DLLs to Execute within the Application

1. Select the application node in the tree view and double click Hander
   Mappings.
2. Click Add Script Map...
3. Type a request path of *.dll, select the IsapiModule module, and
   give it a name.  Click OK.

I did have a some problems like

The Module DLL 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\ClientAccess\Owa\auth\exppw.dll' 
could not be loaded due to a configuration problem. 
The current configuration only supports loading images built for a x86 processor architecture.
The data field contains the error number. 
To learn more about this issue, 
including how to troubleshooting this kind of processor architecture mismatch error, 
see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=29349.

Go to C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

There change

"add name="kerbauth" image="C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\kerbauth.dll"/>"

into

"add name="kerbauth" image="C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\kerbauth.dll" preCondition="bitness64" />"

I use preCondition="bitness64"

That was my solution. This errors cames because the WebOffice was started.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that the Web Service DLL is a 32 bit DLL, which cannot be loaded by a 64 application (IIS in this case). Here are 2 possible solutions: (1) recompile the DLL as a 64 bit DLL, you'll need Delphi XE2 for this. (2) if the DLL is a COM DLL then it is possible to use the Windows wrapper to covert the 32 bit COM DLL into a 64 bit one.

The first option is the best but could be tricky to achieve if you have 3rd party comonents or libraries which are not 64 bit compatible. The second option should work without any recompiling but you do get a bit of a performance hit.

Comment: I've made some Asapi dll in 32bit (with IntraWeb-delphi2010)and these works on IIS7.5 (64bit)

Comment: @Ravaut123 How does a 64 bit process load a 32 bit DLL? Presumably that isn't what you mean.

Comment: I made a asapi dll on my pc (Windows Xp sp3 -32bit). I set the dll in the root map of the pc (Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS7.5 
- 64bit). In the application pools of the IIS you can set .Net Framework version: No Managed code, managed pipeline mode: Classic and Enable 32-bit application: true
I do have some troubles but i fixed to change the config to forse some dll to use the 64bit like
<filter name="Exchange ActiveSync ISAPI Filter" path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\ClientAccess\sync\bin\AirFilter.dll" enabled="true" preCondition="bitness64" />

Comment: @Ravaut123 you should probably post that as a different answer: changing the web app config to enable 32-bits apps is probably the best solution to the OP's problem

Comment: Thanks. @ravaut123 , what s config you are modify , the we.config of you aplication  ? When i control my dll in FF I have a good response ( with my 32 bits dll ) , and the WSDL definition whis my 64 bits dll. But in my web application the Error 404 persist. Qhat s wrong in my proxy compiled URL ? Is not the same way in ISS 6 and ISS 7 ?

Comment: @Benoit - Error404 is a File or Directory not found" error message. is 'http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/WABridge.dll/IWABridge' the right url. Can it be like 'http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/WABridge.dll?IWABridge

Comment: @David Heffernan: IIS isn't a single process, it spawns worker processes that are either 64 bits or 32 bits. A 32 Bits w3wp.exe can perfectly well load a 32 bits DLL.

Comment: Thanks Ravaut123 but this URL works with II6 , with .../soap/IWABridge ... Is s possible that URL ( of SoapHttpClientProtocol ) change in .net 2.0 ?

Comment: The question is can I have static URL in a Web reference proxy on asp.net 2.0  ( like my http://localhost/Services/CPIMServices.dll/soap/IWABridge or not ?